# Pick one cell in range need range.cell when set inside a UDF

Tags: vba, excel, udf

I have created a UDF which works pretty well as it is. However, if the second range is not submitted (it is optional) it will be set to a range inside the UDF.
If i now try to return the range of one cell directly i need to add `.Cells` to the range to select the cell with `(x, y)`.

If no range is submitted it does something like that:

```
Set optional_range = required_range.Columns(2)
Set required_range = required_range.Columns(1)
```

If I later in the UDF want to output a cell from `optional_range` i get this behavior:

```
Set MyFunction = optional_range(x, y)       'cell shows #VALUE
Set MyFunction = optional_range.Cells(x, y) 'shows correct value
```

But as said: if `optional_range` gets a range from the formula directly, it shows the correct value also without the use of `.Cells`.

I can't find a reason for this behavior at all. Can someone tell me why this happens?
The full code can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114425/check-for-legibility-and-speed).

Comment: It is because you are setting the **optional_range** to `.Columns` instead of a range like it would be if you passed in a range. You could bypass the second by using `Set optional_range = required_range.Columns(2).Cells`.

Comment: So I learned something new again... thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is occurring due to setting *optional_range* to the [Range.Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198200.aspx) property and then attempting to piece it out into individual [Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) objects. The Range.Columns and [Range.Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195745.aspx) property properties share many methods with a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) but this is not one of them.

The solution is to simply explicitly set *optional_range* to the .Cells of .Columns(2).

```
Set optional_range = required_range.Columns(2).Cells
'optional truncation to the worksheet's .UsedRange
Set optional_range = Intersect(required_range.Parent.UsedRange, required_range.Columns(2))
```

I have added a way to truncate .Columns(2) down to the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx). Think of it as SUMIF vs. SUMPRODUCT with full column references; particularly helpful if you plan to loop through the cells in *optional_range*. No need to add .Cells to this; the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) returns the cells in the intersection as a true [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).